# Python: os.remove is not working

Tags: python

Why isn't `os.remove(-string-)` working for me? I have the code written as follows:

```
try:
os.remove(a)
    output = current_time() + "\trmv successful"
    message = message + '\n' + output
    message = "".join(message)
    return message

except OSError:
    try:
        os.removedirs(a)
        output = current_time() + "\trmv successful"
        message = message + '\n' + output
        message = "".join(message)
        return message

    except OSError:
        output = current_time() + "\trmv failed: [?]"
        message = message + '\n' + output
        message = "".join(message)
        return message
```

And it would return `21:32:53   rmv failed: [?]` every time I perform the `rmv` command in the client. My Python version is 2.6.1 if that helps.

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to remove?  `os.remove` doesn't work with directories ... and `removedirs` only works if the directories are non-empty.

Comment: What happens if you get no error or exception, and the remove command didn't work anyway?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exceptions are there to be looked at! Check this:

```
try:
    os.remove(a)
except OSError as e: # name the Exception `e`
    print "Failed with:", e.strerror # look what it says
    print "Error code:", e.code
```

Modify your code to display the error message and you'll know why it failed. [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError) can help you.

Comment: Never mind, I used `print "Failed with:", e` and it works fine. Turns out that I don't have enough permissions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try printing out the error?

```
try:
    os.remove(a)
    output = current_time() + "\trmv successful"
    message = message + '\n' + output
    message = "".join(message)
    return message

except OSError, e:
    print ("Failed to remove %s\nError is: %s" % (a,e))
    try:
        os.removedirs(a)
        output = current_time() + "\trmv successful"
        message = message + '\n' + output
        message = "".join(message)
        return message

    except OSError, e:
        print ("Failed twice to remove %s\nError is: %s" % (a,e))
        output = current_time() + "\trmv failed: [?]"
        message = message + '\n' + output
        message = "".join(message)
        return message
```

The error could be literally anything you see... A permissions issue for example?

Comment: Exactly what happened... A permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

try putting some delay time.sleep(0.2) after opening / removing files Or
It seems a windows and/or antivirus issue

Josh Rosenberg on [this](https://bugs.python.org/issue1425127) error tracking on python development points out the same:

Short version: Indexing and anti-virus tools prevent deletion from occurring.

Longer version: 
DeleteFile (and all the stuff that ultimately devolves to DeleteFile) operate in a funny way on Windows. Internally, it opens a HANDLE to the file, marks it as pending deletion, and closes the HANDLE. If no one snuck in and grabbed another HANDLE to the file during that time, then the file is deleted when DeleteFile's hidden HANDLE is closed. Well designed anti-virus/indexing tools use oplocks ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/15/10410965.aspx ) so they can open a file, but seamlessly get out of the way if a normal process needs to take exclusive control of a file or delete it. Sadly "well-designed" is not a term usually associated with anti-virus tools, so errors like this are relatively commonplace.

Workarounds like using GetTempFileName() and MoveFile() to move the file out of the way will work, though I believe they introduce their own race conditions (the temp file itself is created but the HANDLE is closed immediately, which could mean a race to open the empty file by the bad anti-virus that would block MoveFile()).

Basically, if you're running on Windows, and you're using unfriendly anti-virus/indexing tools, there is no clean workaround that maintains the same behavior. You can't keep creating and deleting a file of the same name over and over without risking access denied errors.

That said, you could probably get the same results by opening and closing the file only once. Change from the original pseudocode: