# Cant delete from disk - os.remove dont work

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

Why dont this work?
It print a, iv checked the path and its pointing to the right place.

```
 def delete_file():
    try:
        file2remove = pathtofiles+clicked
        if os.path.exists(file2remove):
            os.remove(file2remove)
            idx = listbox.get(0, tk.END).index(clicked)
            listbox.delete(idx)
        else:
            print("The file does not exist")
    except Exception as e:
        from main import log_error
        log_error(e, "notepad_delete_file")
```

Also change permission with

```
os.chmod(file2remove, "0777")
```

It works like it has deleted it but it doesnt, close the app, flush and it doesnt.

Also this was working yesterday and i havent done any change to the code since then...

Any idea?

Comment: Is there a reason you have two end parenthesis in this line: `os.remove(file2remove))`?

Comment: wxz my bad, but that not why its not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: os.remove is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896046/python-os-remove-is-not-working)

Comment: no because its not giving any error, i update my full code, i have exception and nothing.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48758751/13020139)

Comment: should have mentioned iv tryed this too :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my autosave was messing with this, so i just needed to turn it off when deleting a file

```
                    file2remove=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file2remove)
                    idx = listbox.get(0, tk.END).index(clicked)
                    listbox.delete(idx)
                    valido.set(False)
                    txt_edit.delete('1.0', END)
                    os.chmod(file2remove, 0o777)
                    os.remove(file2remove)
```